# Integer for Text Input on Kivy using Python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm developing an APP and I'm using Kivy, I need to get a user input that's an int/float but I can't get the input as I don't know how to get it, I've read the documentation, went through numerous Stackoverflow and Reddit threads.

This is the code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
import psutil
import os
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput




class BatteryPrototypeApp(App):
    def build(self):

        battery = psutil.sensors_battery()
        plugged = battery.power_plugged
        percent = str(battery.percent)
        plugged = "Plugged In" if plugged else "Not Plugged In"
        
        # limit = int(input("Limite: "))
        label = Label(text=percent+'%')


        limit = TextInput(text='Limit')
        if battery.percent >= limit:
            os.system("start Alarm.mp3")
        
        
        return label
    

app = BatteryPrototypeApp()

app.run()
```

Comment: Try looking at [How to ask user for integer input using Python tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72417465/how-to-ask-user-for-integer-input-using-python-tkinter).